# How can i flip div text back to normal?

Tags: html, flexbox, transform, text-alignment, divide

I trying to flip my text in the chat bubble back to normal. Note: i flip the div with transform: scaleX(-1); as so to get it looking right on the right-side. but a after effect also flip my text inside! Im being at it all day now does anyone have a simply solution to fix this. or if possible do you know how to flip the div chat clip.png instead of the hold thing?

Thx yummi

[image]

```css
body {
    background-color: #6B6B6B;
    margin: 50px;   
    font-family: Arial;
    color: darkgrey;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: .3;
    letter-spacing: .5px;
}   
    .chatbox {
    position: absolute;
    height: 200px;
    width: 400px;
    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-left: 50px;
    border-radius: 0px 0px 30px 30px;
    background-color:rgba(0, 0, 0, .4);
}
    .bubble {
    position: absolute;
    max-width:200px;
    padding: 10px;
    padding-top: 0px;
    border-radius: 0px 20px 20px 20px;
    background-color:rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
}
    .bubble2 {
    position: absolute;
    transform: scaleX(-1);
    max-width:200px;
    padding: 10px;
    padding-top: 0px;
    border-radius: 0px 20px 20px 20px;
    background-color:rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
}
    .chattext {
    font-family: Arial;
    color: grey;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 1.2;
    letter-spacing: .5px;
}
    .right {
    right:50px;
}
    .flip {
    transform: scale(-1, 1);
}
```

```html
<div class="chatbox">

<div class="bubble2 right chattext">
<div><img src="http://wizzfree.com/pix/bubble1.png" width="13" style="margin-left:-23px;">&nbsp;
Yummi: Thx your sooo sweet! </div></div>

<div class="bubble chattext" style="margin-top: 50px;">
<div><img src="http://wizzfree.com/pix/bubble1.png" width="13" style="margin-left:-23px;">&nbsp;
You: how are you do you find your cat? you are so lovely today. what u doing?</div></div>
```

Comment: Instead of that, Why not position everything for the other side (i took the liberty of adjusting other things) https://jsfiddle.net/unv6dgt4/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just add span to text and flip it again

```css
body {
    background-color: #6B6B6B;
    margin: 50px;   
    font-family: Arial;
    color: darkgrey;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: .3;
    letter-spacing: .5px;
}   
    .chatbox {
    position: absolute;
    height: 200px;
    width: 400px;
    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-left: 50px;
    border-radius: 0px 0px 30px 30px;
    background-color:rgba(0, 0, 0, .4);
}
    .bubble {
    position: absolute;
    max-width:200px;
    padding: 10px;
    padding-top: 0px;
    border-radius: 0px 20px 20px 20px;
    background-color:rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
}
    .bubble2 {
    position: absolute;
    transform: scaleX(-1);
    max-width:200px;
    padding: 10px;
    padding-top: 0px;
    border-radius: 0px 20px 20px 20px;
    background-color:rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
}
.bubble2 span{
    transform: scale(-1, 1);
    display: inline-flex;
}
    .chattext {
    font-family: Arial;
    color: grey;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 1.2;
    letter-spacing: .5px;
}
    .right {
    right:50px;
}
    .flip {
    transform: scale(-1, 1);
}
```

```html
<div class="chatbox">

<div class="bubble2 right chattext">
<div><img src="http://wizzfree.com/pix/bubble1.png" width="13" style="margin-left:-23px;">&nbsp;
<span>Yummi: Thx your sooo sweet! </span></div></div>

<div class="bubble chattext" style="margin-top: 50px;">
<div><img src="http://wizzfree.com/pix/bubble1.png" width="13" style="margin-left:-23px;">&nbsp;
You: how are you do you find your cat? you are so lovely today. what u doing?</div></div>
```

Comment: thx shahryar, looks great... but is it possible to take out that under lay line which is cuz by the clip image to near the edge?

Comment: that line mostly show on firefox and for prevent this bug is better use css code to make bubble chat effect , see examples http://jsfiddle.net/ThinkingStiff/mek5Z/